# Collinearity of a given points with a parametric equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have points moving on a circular orbit with parametric equations

I want to find "t" when they lie on a single straight line (Collinearity)

```
R = {0.9836, 9.9886, 5.099, 1.496}
o = {6.278, 0.213223, 0.529, 3.33}

y1[t_] := R[[1]] Sin[o[[1]] t];
x1[t_] := R[[1]] Cos[o[[1]] t];

y2[t_] := R[[2]] Sin[o[[2]] t];
x2[t_] := R[[2]] Cos[o[[2]] t];

y3[t_] := R[[3]] Sin[o[[3]] t];
x3[t_] := R[[3]] Cos[o[[3]] t];

y4[t_] := R[[4]] Sin[o[[4]] t];
x4[t_] := R[[4]] Cos[o[[4]] t];
```

The equation of a straight line is given by  $y = a x + b$.

in my case, I have four equations (Condition of Collinearity)

$$y1[t] = a * x1[t] + b$$
$$y2[t] = a * x2[t] + b$$
$$y3[t] = a * x3[t] + b$$
$$y4[t] = a * x4[t] + b$$

I tried to solve a system of equations for t

it works for n=3

```
FindRoot[{ y1[T] == a x1[T] + b,
           y2[T] == a x2[T] + b,
           y3[T] == a x3[T] + b}, {{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {T, 10}}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Black, Point[{x1[t], y1[t]}], 
Point[{x2[t], y2[t]}], Point[{x3[t], y3[t]}]}, Axes -> True, 
PlotRange -> 10], {t, 0, 9.81, 2 \[Pi]/360}]
```

[image]

but there is no answer for n = 4 or more points...

```
FindRoot[{ y1[T] == a x1[T] + b,
           y2[T] == a x2[T] + b,
           y3[T] == a x3[T] + b},
           y4[T] == a x4[T] + b},{{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {T, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: 4  equations for 3 unknowns do not have a general solutions. Only if the frequencies o have a special relationship can there be a singular solution. Therefore, where do your frequencies come from?

Comment: It looks to me that you are trying to compute the time between two perfect conjunctions of the earth with Mars, Jupiter and Saturn. I think your model -- circular orbits and all orbits lying in a common plane in too naive to give you a meaningful result. However, there is no harm in exploring such a model as an intellectual toy, but you should work with orbital periods and you will have to add the assumption that the periods can be expressed as rational multiples of the earth's period to get anywhere.

Comment: You might find this [Wolfram Blog article](https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/12/17/2020s-winter-solstice-hosts-the-greatest-conjunction-in-nearly-four-hundred-years) interesting. It won't save your problem, but it deals beautifully with the current conjunction and might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find values of t where 3 points are aligned as there are many such values. Here I use the fact that lines between the initial point (smallest R) and subsequent points will all have the same slope and I ask for four such values between 0 and 1000:

```
FindInstance[
 x > 0 && x < 1000 && (y2[x] - y1[x])/(x2[x] - x1[x]) == (y3[x] - y1[x])/(x3[x] -
       x1[x]), {x}, Reals, 4]

(* {{x -> 29.1393}, {x -> 39.8519}, {x -> 219.022}, {x -> 119.553}} *)
```

But the perfect alignment of 4 points is a rare event at best. Using the same approach does not appear to find a single instance (at least not in a reasonable time).

```
FindInstance[
 x > 0 && (y2[x] - y1[x])/(x2[x] - x1[x]) == (y3[x] - y1[x])/(x3[x] - 
      x1[x]) && (y2[x] - y1[x])/(x2[x] - x1[x]) == (y4[x] - 
      y1[x])/(x4[x] - x1[x]), {x}, Reals, 1]
```